# Robolectric's Shadow Object for Bluetooth

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, junit4, robolectric

Good day,

I made a android program which open bluetooth socket with another device, then exchange data with this device.

I am trying to make unit test for it, but I dont know how to make a shadow for the bluetoothDevice, how to test the connection, or the how to work virtualy with the another connected device.

I try to read the Robolectric documentaion, but it did not help me.

Anybody can please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty old question, but I'll go ahead and answer.  You should be able to get your ShadowBluetoothDevice with something like this:

```
ShadowBluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = shadowOf(ShadowBluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice("00:07:80:78:A4:69"));
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I get 
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothService(BluetoothAdapter.java:2095)
 at android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.getService(BluetoothDevice.java:608)
 at android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.__constructor__(BluetoothDevice.java:646)
 at android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.<init>(BluetoothDevice.java)
 at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(BluetoothAdapter.java:541)